# The language level is locked at 1.8 on Rubymine for ruby 2.2.3

Tags: ruby, rubymine

After installing `ruby 2.2.3`, the `rubymine 6.0.1` still has language level locked at `1.8` (not open for choose) causing error in debug gem installation. There are few posts reporting the similar issue and none of them gives a clear answer (one is suggesting upgrading rubymine from 5.4 to 6). How to make the language level compatible with ruby version?

[image]

Comment: Why 6.0? Latest RubyMine version is 8.0! Is there any particular reason?

Comment: That's what we are having. According to a post, rubymine 6/7/8 are all having the similar issue.

Comment: Could you try the latest RubyMine version (or 8.5. EAP)? There should be no problem with it. In addition, if your version is 6.3.3, then it was released before ruby 2.2.0

Comment: `Olivia`, I don't have official license for ver 8 (likely will work). Is older version of ruby going to work?

Comment: Any updates on this question?